# safely killing a background process

Tags: bash, job-control

I'm writing data to a pipe in a parent process. The parent process creates a background job that reads data from the pipe & write it to the screen & to a log file.
How can I know when to kill the background job? `wait` command simply waits forever. I prefer to not use a token to detect the "end of output". Code example:

```
function log()
{
    if [ -z "$counter" ]; then
        counter=1
    else
        (( ++counter ))
    fi

    if ! [[ -z "$teepid" ]]; then
        # ***** How can I know if it's safe to kill here?
        kill $teepid
    fi
    # Display text-to-be-logged on screen
    #  & write text-to-be-logged to it's corresponding log file
    tee <"$pipe" 1>&4 "${logs_dir}/${counter}_${1// /_}" &
    teepid=$!
}

logs_dir="/path/to/log/dir"

pipe_dir=$(mktemp -d)
pipe="${pipe_dir}/cmds_output"
mkfifo "$pipe"
exec 3<>"$pipe" # link file descriptor (FD) #3 to $pipe for r/w
exec 4<&1   # save value of FD1 to FD4
exec 1>&3   # redirect all output to FD3

log # Logs the following code block
{
    # ... Many bash commands ...
}

log # Logs the following code block
{
    # ... Many bash commands ...
}

if ! [[ -z "$teepid" ]]; then
    # ***** How can I know if it's safe to kill here? Maybe it's still logging
    kill $teepid;
fi
```

---

**Edit:**

I tried:

```
exec 3>&-
#exec 1>&- # Have tried also uncommenting this row
wait $teepid
exec 3<>"$pipe"
exec 1>&3
kill $teepid
```

but the wait command still hangs...
I found that `ps -o pid,ppid,s --pid $teepid` shows the state of the process. Should I count on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just close the pipe when you are done.  The child process will reach EOF and should exit.

Comment: What do you mean by "close the pipe"? What's the code for that..?

Comment: You created it by redirecting fd number 3 to the pipe, so you can close it by redirecting it somewhere else ( /dev/null maybe? ).

Comment: Actually it looks like you can close an fd by redirecting it to "&-", as in 3>&-.

Comment: I tried that... doesn't help

Comment: @Dor need to be more specific.  You also don't want either of those kill $teepid statements.

Comment: OK. see my edit please. "You also don't want either of those kill $teepid statements." - yep, I suppose. But the process still hangs.

Comment: @Dor the way your code is structured, tee is inheriting fd 4, so it is keeping itself open.  Close it before running tee, like this: ( exec 4>&- ; tee <"$pipe" 1>&4 "${logs_dir}/${counter}_${1// /_}" ) &

Comment: I think that inheriting FD4 isn't the problem, but you were correct about closing the pipe. See the final solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655905/logging-blocks-of-code-to-log-files-in-bash/6685244#6685244